# delete value from listview and database as well in onitemlongclick listener

Tags: java, android

On clicking on ListView it deletes the value from ListView at index but not deleted that value from that index again.

for eg., it deletes the value from index 1 and again if I delete that value it doesn't delete from index 1. deleted from another index if selected other index

**onItemLongClickListener  (Book.class)**

```
        lview.setOnItemLongClickListener(new 
        AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View 
           view, int i, long l) {

            String parse = String.valueOf(i);

            Integer deletedrows =  mydb.DeleteData(String.valueOf(i));
            if(deletedrows > 0 )
            {

                Toast.makeText(BookList.this, "deleted" + parse, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
            else
            {

                Toast.makeText(BookList.this, "not Deleted" + parse, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            return true;
        }
```

**Set data on list view  (Book.class)**

```
      public void getdata()
       {

     ListAdapter lviewAdapter;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> userList;

        userList = mydb.getalldata();
        if(userList.isEmpty())
        {
           showdata("Error","Nothing Found");
           return;
        }
         ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

       lviewAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(BookList.this, userList, 
        R.layout.book_custom_list,
            new String[]{"ID","url","title"},
            new int[]{  R.id.customid,R.id.customurl,R.id.customtitle});
       lview.setAdapter(lviewAdapter);


   }
```

**getdata method (Database Helper.class)**

```
   public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getalldata()
    {
      SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
      ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> userList = new ArrayList<>();
      Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from " + TABLE_NAME,null);

    while (cursor.moveToNext()){
        HashMap<String,String> user = new HashMap<>();
        user.put("ID",cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Id_name)));

    user.put("title",cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(title_name)));
        user.put("url",cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(url_name)));
        userList.add(user);
    }
    return userList;
```

delete data also affected the id showing in the list view, want that to change the id to 1,2,3 in sequential form. thanks

Comment: Populate the Listview from the database and remove the item on delete using Database query and refresh the listview. It saves a lot of time for you @Harpreet

Comment: can you please elaborate it, I didn't get you properly.

Comment: Sure I will do it @Harpreet

Comment: First, get the data from the server and store that in the SQLite Database and populate it in Listview. Now on long click of item remove the row of that id from the local database and refresh the data and populate in listview again @Harpreet

Comment: Before that tell me how are you getting the data? From the server? @Harpreet

Comment: its already in the database, no server here.

Comment: From where you are getting the data? Is it static data? @Harpreet

Comment: In Long Click, it doesn't delete the item from that index again.

Comment: it's a bookmark tab in browser section, on clicking on bookmark button data saved to database and show in bookmark tab

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
 lview.setOnItemLongClickListener(new 
    AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
        @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View 
       view, int i, long l) {

        String parse = String.valueOf(i);

        //Add this code when you try to delete the item

        try{
        SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
        String query = "delete from TABLE_NAME where id like "+"'"+(ListView_ID)+"'";
        db.delete(TABLE_ORDERS, KEY_LISTVIEW_ID + "='" + LISTVIEW_ID+ "'", null);
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query,null);
        cursor.close();

        //Now set the Data in the ListView from the database after you delete the item
        getFreshData();
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        Log.e("order_proof",""+e);
    }

        return true;
    }




private void getFreshData(){

 String query = "SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME";
 ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> userList = new ArrayList<>();
  Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from " + TABLE_NAME,null);

while (cursor.moveToNext()){
    HashMap<String,String> user = new HashMap<>();
    user.put("ID",cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Id_name)));

user.put("title",cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(title_name)));
    user.put("url",cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(url_name)));
    userList.add(user);
}
return userList;

//populate this list in the ListView.
}
```

Let me know after you add this code @Harpreet.